# Book about teenagers on a spaceship, terraforming a planet

Tags: story-identification

I read the book around 20 years ago, in german.
It's not hard scifi, but a typical young adult book.

I think the kids were somehow awakened (maybe genetically produced?) too early, and now have to terraform the closest planet in order to survive. I remember that they all had greek names, I think the main character was called gamma.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found it: "Andymon: Eine Weltraum-Utopie" by Angela Steinmüller and Karlheinz Steinmüller. Just in case anyone else tries to find it some day:

> https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6279653-andymon

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting button. But, rather than quoting the URL, maybe link it to the title and quote a summary?